# Getting timeout accessing jenkins setup on ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

i am new to aws, and trying to set up an ec2 instance and setup jenkins over it.
I have managed to install jenkins but when trying to access jenkins UI on default 8080. I am getting timeout.
I am not sure what I am missing?

I installed jenkins over ec2 and want to access jenkins UI page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define security group inbound rules for EC2 instance for port 8080, which is used by Jenkins.
This article guide you through the process of setting up an AWS EC2 instance with Ubuntu OS and Jenkins.

https://solutiontoolkit.com/2023/04/complete-guide-setting-up-aws-ec2-instance-with-ubuntu-os-and-jenkins/